What product can I use to seal gaps in rim joists?
According to google, caulk has a limited lifespan (a random webpage claims 5 years for interior caulk, and 5-25 years for exterior caulk).
I am sealing up some rim joists, which will then be covered by a drywall ceiling. I never want to think about these rim joists again.
What kind of sealant will adhere to wood, will last long term, and is appropriate for interior use? I am not looking for a specific product, but a class of product. At the same time, I would like to ask - am I overthinking it?

For interior use, to simply block airflow, just about anything is fine. It isn't subjected to temperature extremes, significant moisture, or sunlight, which are the primary reason caulks fail over time. Use what makes sense for your specific situation.

Silicone1, urethane2, or latex3 caulk

Foam rope caulk

Urethane2 spray foam6

Rubber flashing tape4 or aluminum tape5

Rigid insulation panels

House wrap or poly sheeting




Silicone emits a rather smelly odor as it cures. That clears fairly quickly with adequate airflow.

Urethane does not come off. It's for that reason that it's ideal for some home improvement projects. It'll bond permanently to floors, walls, clothes, skin, or whatever. Take precautions.

Latex shrinks a lot and isn't as tough. It cleans up with water, though.

Most flashing tape is designed to stick to house wrap. Find one that claims to bond well to wood.

This stuff is fun to work with and bonds well. It tears easily, though, so don't use it where movement is expected.

Spray foam in consumer cans comes in at least three varieties: Standard (high expansion), window and door (low expansion) and fire-blocking. Select the appropriate one for your needs.



One nitpick -- the smell from one-part RTV silicones isn't a solvent, but a chemical that's released during the curing reaction.  (in typical formulations, that chemical is acetic acid, aka the stuff that makes vinegar...vinegar-y :)
